# primary key definition on tables

Tags: database-design, primary-key, rdbms

I had a small debate with one of my colleagues that is in charge of designing some tables in one of our software products.

My colleague suggests using a structure like this, I reduce the tables to only a few columns to go straight to the point:

```
Table Buildings

Columns: buildingId,address,zipcode, ...
PK: buildingId

Table Offices

Columns: buildingId, officeId, officeName, ...
PK: buildingId, officeId

Table Workers

Columns: buildingId, OfficeId, workerId, name, surname
PK: buildingId, OfficeId, workerId
```

Choosing "by definition" to use surrogate keys like `buildingId`, `OfficeId` and `workingId`, I told my opinion that is:

1. The PK of the first table is ok to me
2. the PK of the second table is `officeId` and `buildingId` is a FK
3. the PK of the third table is `workerId` and `officeId` is a FK and I will omit `BuildingId` completely because is redundant.

So the result will be like this:

```
Table Buildings

Columns: buildingId,address,zipcode, ...
PK: buildingId

Table Offices

Columns: buildingId, officeId, officeName, ...
PK: officeId
FK: buildingId

Table Workers

Columns: officeId, workerId, name, surname
PK: workerId
FK: officeId
```

My colleague told me that choosing the PKs as he suggested is more natural and the performance querying these tables using these PKs will be better, also the parent/child relation will be more clear

For example, he told me that making a query in his model on the table Workers querying using `officeId` and `buildingId` will be faster than only using `officeId`.

In my opinion, using `buildingId` in the table Workers is denormalization and can cause problems in the future (for example losing data integrity with an update error that updates `buildingId` in a non-correct manner on the table Workers).

I think that a correct usage of indexes is the correct way to improve performance in situations like this and not declaring "parent tables PK" as part of "child table" PKs. I think also that "parent/child" relations are more hierarchical DBMS than RDBMS.

Any suggestion?

Comment: But the real question is: `can a worker work for more than one office?`

Comment: The PKs should follow the features of the real world, not the esthetics of the proposed design.  For workerids, what is your colleague going to do when a worker moves from one office to another?

Comment: I think the major problem is what he will do to the workers if the office will change building... He will have to update the buildingId of all the workers with the officeId is moving to another builing, the buildingId in the offices table instead of changing only the builingId in the offices table...

Comment: How is this different from the years old natural key vs. surrogate key arguments? Your colleague supports natural keys while you supports surrogate keys. The Codd fanatics will tell you that natural keys is the only way to go. I would say that they are wrong, and surrogate keys does have their advantages, as long as the natural keys are properly and uniquely indexed. I'm afraid this question is primarily opinion based, as as such it's off topic to stackoverflow.

Comment: Your colleague's design isn't necessarily wrong but it's unusual and will require more effort to implement, change and keep consistent than your model.

Comment: @ZoharPeled This isn't a natural vs surrogate keys debate, it's all surrogate keys. This is more like regular vs weak entity sets in ER modeling.

Comment: exactly ZoharPeled, you are right. I think that buildingId should not be on the workers table because IMO is a denormalization. that can cause referential integrity problems (a worker that works in officeId 1 in the buildingId 1 and anotther that works in officeId 1 in the buildingId 2 when the officeId 1 is, fox example is in buildingId 1 in the offices table...)

Comment: @AlexArre again, this is opinion based. referential integrity is being enforced by foreign key constraints. it has nothing to do with the choice between natural keys or surrogate keys. the natural key approach is a valid approach, and codd fanatics will say it's the only valid approach.

Comment: but the question isn't about natural vs surrogate key, maybe I could't properly express myself. The question is if having buildingId in workers table PK is correct, or if buildingId have to be omitted because is redundant...

Comment: If you decide to go with a natural key system, the building id must be a part of the workers table primary key. If you decide to go with a surrogate key system, then using the building id in the workers table is redundant.